# Кавычки при аббревиатуре

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика, аббревиатуры

А как быть с кавычками в следующих примерах: МБУК ЦМБС- надо ли выделять кавычками ЦМБС. МБУК "Центральная межпоселенческая библиотечная система"- здесь понятно, а вот при аббревиатуре кавычки сохраняются? Я только нашла типа: ОАО "РЖД", ОАО "МТС", но это названия коммерческих организаций. А как в моем примере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кавычек в аббревиатуре не бывает. Это по логике. Или просто *РЖД* или *ОAO "Российские железные дороги"*. Дело в том, что нечто, в подобных случаях попадающее в кавычки, фактически выполняет роль некоторого имени собственного. А имена собственные не подлежат сокращениям до аббревиатур. Если же сама аббревиатура становится именем собственным, то её уже и закавычивать не надо. Ну это все в идеале, конечно. Реально бороться едва ли возможно.

Есть и одно узаконенное исключение, диктуемое, увы, не филологами, а "афффтаритетами" от политики, бюрократами и юристами. Дело в том, что нет никаких ограничений на уставное название предприятия. И если кто-то **зарегистрировал** предприятие или торговую марку типа *АБВ "ЁПРСТ"*, то приходится так и писать. По счастью, это довольно редкий случай. Впрочем, и тут можно считать, что в кавычках стоит не аббревиатура как таковая, а узаконенное имя. При этом совершенно не важно, стоит ли за этой якобы-аббревиатурой что-то или это просто набор букв.

Answer (score 1):

Нечто, именуемое вами «Центральная межпоселенческая библиотечная система», является абстрактной сущностью и поэтому выделяется кавычками. В простой нашей повседневной жизни с системами никто и никогда не встретится, а встретится с конкретной библиотекой, с конкретным экраном компьютера, на котором будет изображена графическая часть сайта, и так далее...  Если бы речь шла о единственной на всю округу и всем хорошо известной Межпоселенческой библиотеке Энского района, тогда бы и кавычек не нужно было. Для лучшего понимания кавычки лучше оставить: МБУК «ЦМБС» (мы-бук цэ-эм-бэ-эс). Таких МБУК может быть очень много, и у каждого будет название, которые пишутся в кавычках. Хотя, если посмотреть с другой стороны, лучше не ставьте никаких кавычек — кому известно что такое эта самая библиотечная система — и так поймет о чем идет речь, а тот, кому не известно, — только еще больше запутается. Ведь он воспримет аббревиатуру, выделенную кавычками, как наименование ошибочно. Отсутствие кавычек у аббревиатуры будет сигналом читателю о том, что эта аббревиатура является каким-то весьма локальным сокращением.

Comment: Я столько не выпью.